# How to reslove the appium crash?

Tags: android, appium

1. I have installed appium 1.3.7 version in mac machine.
2. I have started  appium server for android app in android device.
3. In android device, the app get installed and opened successfully.
4. I have clicked the show inspector button and then I can able to see the inspector screen and then my appium inspector get crashed.

[image: I have attached the screenshot below for reference.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using an older version of appium 1.3.1 which is quite stable. Maybe try a reinstall of appium and if that doesn't work go back to an older version.